# Query Azure from iOS

Tags: ios, service, azure, web

I am not figuring out how to perform a query in Azure. I did finally figure out inserts, but now I am trying to query from Azure. Two parts here, how do I return the result from Azure and how do I read the results in objective-C?

Thus far, I have this

```
-(double)GetValidAppVersion
{
// Create a proxy client for sending requests to the Azure platform.
MSClient *client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString : @""
                                         withApplicationKey : @"];
MSTable *appSettingsTable = [client getTable:@"AppSettings"];
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Key == AppVersion"];
NSArray *queryResults = [[NSArray alloc] init];
[appSettingsTable readWhere:predicate completion:^(NSArray *results, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error)
{
    self.items = [results mutableCopy];
}];

return 1.0;
```

}

I have not figured out the Azure side either. How can I query and return a result based on the input parameter?

My table is simple with 
ID int
Key varchar
Value varchar

Any help with getting this going is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I added this to my controller

```
-(bool) IsAppVersionValid
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
double validAppVersion = [delegate.appVersion doubleValue];
double serverAppVersion;

NSDictionary *item = @{ @"complete" : @(NO) };
[self.Service SelectAppVersion:item completion:^(NSUInteger index)
{
}];

return true;//clientVersion >= validAppVersion;
}
```

And this to my service (this is sloppy as it should be a simple completion block -- I would like to pass NSString * with the AppSettings key value and use that in the predicate as well. Any thoughts on the syntax for that?

```
typedef void (^CompletionWithAppVersionBlock)(NSUInteger index);

- (void) SelectAppVersion:(NSDictionary *) item
completion:() completion;
```

Answer (score 2):

All of the read table read methods that are part of the iOS SDK for Mobile Services are asynchronous which means that you have to pass a completion block into them (as you're doing above where you're setting self.items = [results mutableCopy];) in order to then do something with the results they are fetching.

This means that in order to get the value you're looking for, you'll want to pass in a completion block into your GetValidAppVersion method.  You can then pass the app version you're getting back to that block.  So something like this:

```
-(void) GetValidAppVersion:(NSDictionary *)item completion:(CompletionWithVersion)completion
{
    MSTable *appSettingsTable = [client getTable:@"AppSettings"];
    NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Key == AppVersion"];
    NSArray *queryResults = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    [appSettingsTable readWhere:predicate completion:^(NSArray *results, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error)
    {
        completion([results objectAtIndex:0]);
    }];
}
```

You would need to define the CompletionWithVersion as being a block with a parameter returned (the AppVersion).  Take a look at the iOS quickstart application to see how the completion blocks are defined.

Comment: Provided it's now working, I'd read up on blocks to get a better understanding (like here: http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-iOS--Day-7%E2%80%93Making-Network-Requests). Essentially the MSTable calls (such as readWhere) expect to take in a block of code that they can call when they are finished.  There is no way (outside of taking a look at the SDK and figuring out how to make a synchronous call) to do what you were originally doing.  Does that help?